# FatFs SD Card Writing OK; Reading Partially

Tags: sd-card, stm32f4, fatfs

I followed this link [STM32 SD Card Example](https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/microcontrollers/stm32/stm32-sd-card-interfacing-with-example/) to have made FatFs library work on my STM32 F411 PCB board.

Basically I need to store 1000+ floating point values in SD card and read them back.
I have no problem in writing; but I cannot read all the records back.

I put each value in one line, ending with "\n" and use f_gets to read line by line.
After reading 900+ line, I have Assertion failed error.

Can anybody shed some light on what might be the causes and how to resolve?